# Make Sure Database Records Are Consecutive

Tags: iphone, database, core-data, rss, timeline

I'm making an iPhone RSS app which downloads articles from the Internet, then cache them in a database. I fetch 25 articles at a time from the Internet, but the problem is that when the last fetch is from a long time ago, there will be a gap between the latest 25 articles and the cached 25 articles. This means that I need to continue to download the articles between them. But, how could I know wether or not the two fetch's articles are consecutive? Do I need some flags in the database? Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Kai.

Comment: In theory you should be storing some kind of date along with it, and it would be easiest to just create a predicate for sorting based on that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a timestamp for all your articles, get the latest timestamp of your stored items (this will give you the latest stored RSS article) and start comparing it with the timestamp of items to be fetched.

Once you find the first date that is newer than your local stored one, it's the point where you want to start fetching new results.

Comment: The problem is I may need to redownload the next 25 articles to make sure the articles are consecutive even if the articles have been already downloaded.

Comment: @nonamelive: Of course. That's something you have to live with.